# Segmentation fault (Core dumped) error when trying to populate a 2d matrix

Tags: c

I'm trying to populate my 2D array with random integers.

```
//rows, cols are randomly generated ints between 1 and 10
int rows = rand()%10 +1;
int cols = rand()%10 +1;

int arr[rows][cols];
for (i = 0; i <rows; i++){
 for (j=0; i<cols; j++){
  arr[i][j] = rand()%10;
}}
```

Every time I try to run this code, it gives me a segmentation default.

I edited the post to give the actual code I am running

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. Please provide code you actually ran!

Comment: Except for the missing `;` on the variable declaration line, this code is fine. The segfault is being caused by something else.

Comment: post all code please

Comment: You are supposed to proofread your code for elementary errors and silly typos before asking questions on SO. If you cannot tell `i` from `j` maybe you should use more distinctive names for your variables.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it's because the `i < ...` which should be a `j < ...` in `for (j=0; i<cols; j++)`;